# How can Deserialize with Javascript Serializer? (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, json, list, serialization

```
public class SocialFriends
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my Class.

```
List<SocialFriends> oList2 = ser.Deserialize<List<SocialFriends>>(response.Content);
```

I'm getting data's like this. But it returns 0 data :S

Data is here

```
{"data":[{"name":"George","id":"511222445"},{"name":"Mayk","id":"517247768"}]}
```

I can't explain this problem? Can anybody say, where is my fault?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class

```
class Data 
{
    public SocialFriends[] data { get; set; }
}
```

and change your code to:

```
Data oList2 = ser.Deserialize<Data>(response.Content);
```

Comment: I used Your solution, and it worked, thanks. I getted the datas like this. 
foreach (var friend in oList2.data)
                    Response.Write(friend.id);

Answer (score 1):

This code works.

```
public class SocialFriendsData
{
    public List<SocialFriends> Data { get; set; }
}

public class SocialFriends
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialization:**

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string response = "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"George\",\"id\":\"511222445\"},{\"name\":\"Mayk\",\"id\":\"517247768\"}]}";
 SocialFriendsData oList2 = ser.Deserialize<SocialFriendsData>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrapped in a `data` property. You'll have to grab the JSON string out of that `data` property. I don't know which JSON serializer you use, but based on what you provided, the easiest way is probably just to create an intermediate `DataHolder` class:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it like this:

```
var dataHolder = ser.Deserialize<DataHolder>(response.Content);
var oList2 = ser.Deserialize<List<SocialFriends>>(dataHolder.Data);
```

If you're using a robust JSON serializer like Json.NET, you can even skip the intermediate deserialization and change your DataHolder type to the correct type:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public List<SocialFriends> SocialFriends { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this code to get the data:

```
var dataHolder = ser.Deserialize<DataHolder>(response.Content);
var oList2 = dataHolder.SocialFriends;
```

Comment: That would completely depend on your JSON serializer. I know Json.NET doesn't care.